# weird bug in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2012

why does this code compiles and run on visual studio 2012? is this just a bug or i missing something

```
namespace SSSS
    {
        namespace SSS
        {
            template <class T>
            class SS
            {
            public:
                typedef T ValueType;
                SS(){std::cout<<T();}
                SS(T t) { std::cout<<t;}
            };

            typedef SS<double> DD;
        }
    }
    int main()
    {
        SSSS::SSS::DD::SS d;
    }
```

Comment: VS 2012 or 2013? And what do you expect to happen when this code is compiled?

Comment: Why do you expect it not to compile and run?

Comment: I expect, that compiler must warn, that the SSSS::SSS::DD::SS is not a type.

Comment: Please add that to the question so that it is complete.

Comment: the correct syntax should be `class SSSS::SSS::DD::SS d;`, this might be simply a bug in VS

Comment: @MikeSeymour because the name refers to class' constructor, not the type, but I guess you just want a clarification from OP

Comment: Except that `DD::SS` **is** a type, the injected type name inside the class `DD`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: But the name refers to the constructor, not the class, as described by [class.qual]/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your compiler is interpreting `SS` as the injected class name; in which case, it is a type, so the declaration is valid.

However, the name lookup rules say that it should instead be interpreted as the constructor, not the class, so your compiler is wrong. Others reject the code: http://ideone.com/7fJ1VM

Valid type names would be the type alias `DD`, or an elaborated type specifier using the injected class name, `class DD::SS`.

Comment: I am not sure I can agree with the second paragraph. That is based on [class.qual]/2 that starts with: *In a lookup in which the constructor is an acceptable lookup result*. In the context of the expression, I don't think the constructor is a valid result (the address cannot be taken, it cannot be explicitly called by user code, this cannot be a constructor declaration...), which means that the whole paragraph does not apply and that is not the reason for the failure. [Also `clang` accepts the code, so two out of three accept it]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Name lookup doesn't take context into account, since the context can't be determined until the meanings of the names are known. It includes an example which states that it does refer to the constructor here. `A::A a; // error, A::A is not a type name`

Comment: Uhm... looking at the C++14 standard it seems that the wording above has been the subject of a DR, as it now reads: *lookup in which function names are not ignored33 and the nested-name-specifier nominates a class C:* with some later wording *Such a constructor name shall be used only in the declarator-id of
a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration*. My understanding of the rule I remembered seems to be wrong and `gcc` is right here [against `clang` and `VS`, in agreement with `xlC` and Solaris' `CC` --which I just tried]

Comment: ... the (33 note mentions the three cases where functions are ignored: *nested-name-specifier* (i.e. the `SS` in `DD::SS::DD`) *elaborated-type-specifier* (i.e. `class DD::SS`) or *base-specifier*: `struct X : DD::SS`